# How to plot markers in Maps Components or Google Maps Overlay Component - Pentaho?

Tags: google-maps, maps, pentaho, marker

I'm using Pentaho 4.8 and the plugin CDE for showing information in maps. I have followed the Map Component Reference, but I don't know what I am missing. The resultset is as they mentioned, but when I launch the preview it doesn't end to load.
I don't know what else I have to create, maybe a js file with something unknown? Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Do the samples work ?

If they do, you must be missing some step. Check the javascript console logs. maybe those will give you a clue.